# Inconclusiveness of Ratio Test

Tags: sequences-and-series

When using the Ratio Test, having $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| > 1$$ is inconclusive. However, I'm having trouble imagining how such a series $\sum a_n$ could possibly converge. Is it because when examining the sequence $\left\{\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\right\}$, there is a subsequence that converges to something greater than one, while the rest of the sequence stays below one?

Comment: what makes you think this situation is inconclusive? Besides, look at what happens when $a_n=2^n$.

Comment: Usual Ratio Test is for series. And do you mean converge?

Comment: Thanks for catching my mistakes, André!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the series 
$$1+2+ r+2r +r^2+2r^2+r^3+2r^3+\cdots,$$
where (say) $r=\frac{1}{10}$.  The series clearly converges, but $\limsup \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=2$.

The ratio $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is "often" large, but it is also often small, and the small, in this example, beats the large.

Comment: Your last sentence was a great explanation. Thanks!